# BSC Testnet: Truffle Migrate ETIMEDOUT

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain

I need to deploy my smart contract to BSC Testnet

I always got this :

```
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: ETIMEDOUT
```

I tried to change the RPC specified here https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html#rate-limit

All of them, yet still the same.

One thing is, I tried to deploy it to ropsten instead just for fun.
And it is success.
Is there any problem with BSC Testnet RPC nowadays ?

Here is my snip for truffle-config.js

```
        testnet: {
            provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545`),
            network_id: 97, // 3 for ropsten, 97 for bsc test
            confirmations: 2,
            timeoutBlocks: 2000,
            skipDryRun: true,
            networkCheckTimeout: 1000000
        },
```

I searched, some people use websocket (wss), some change the RPC Url, some add the networkCheckTimeout.
I tried all of them (except wss, since I don't see it is provided by BSC Testnet).
But nothing work.

Any suggestion ? Thank you

Comment: Not working here too

Comment: hey did you ever figure this out? having the same issue on bsc testnet

Comment: @TylerJones Not at all. but I did found an alternative. Instead of using truffle, I used remix. It was able to be deployed successfully with same RPC URL If you are not strictly bind to truffle, you could try remix.

Answer (score 2):

When I used other endpoints, The issue was fixed. You can try the below endpoints.

**BSC RPC Endpoints:**

```
https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/
https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s1.binance.org:8545/
https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545/
https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s2.binance.org:8545/
https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s3.binance.org:8545/
https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s3.binance.org:8545/
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched for more than a week. Finally, I found the answer [here](https://www.cnblogs.com/softfair/p/Truffle-migirate-deploy-contract-ESOCKETTIMEDOUT.html), Not only change the `pollingInterval`, but also do this: in the module `web3-provider-engine`， modify the `timeout` a bigger number. Remember that, the module maybe imported more than one times, so change the value everywhere in your projects.

```
xhr({
    uri: targetUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newPayload),
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    timeout: 2000,  // change the value bigger
```

The `timeout` value is hardcoded, maybe nowadays most people have very good Internet connection and only a few techs suffering, I tried very hard to find out the answer. After I change this configuration, I never suffer timeout!

Answer (score 0):

```js
bsc: {
  networkCheckTimeout: 999999,
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`),
  network_id: 97, // Ropsten's id
  gas: 5500000, // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
  confirmations: 10, // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
  timeoutBlocks: 200, // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
  skipDryRun: true // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
},
```

adding network timeout should help

Comment: Is the timeout measured in seconds or milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that BSC produces blocks so quickly that it exceeds the default number of blocks Truffle is configured to wait for. You can solve this by adding the `networkCheckTimeout` and `timeoutBlocks` fields in your network config:

```json
bsc: {
  networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,
  timeoutBlocks: 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to avoid this error is to

```
truffle compile
```

manually before migration.

Then, when migrate, to add the --compile-none option.

```
truffle migrate --network xxx --compile-none
```